# Authenticate with AWS Cognito in an AppSync API for using a subscription in my VUE js app

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

Hi I am creating a Vue app and I want to use an AWS AppSync Subscription for updating the content of a web app page in realtime.
I know that I can create an app using the AWS Amplify service, but I would like to create my Vue app on my own.
I am able to connect to AppSync API using an aws api key but now I want to use the additional authorization provider in order to authenticate with AWS Cognito using a token that a user logged in my app would already have. For connecting with api key i follow [this documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/vue/build-a-backend/graphqlapi/connect-to-api/)
I paste here the main code I use for connecting and working with the AppSync subscription:

in the main.js of my vue app I have:

```
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    API: {
      GraphQL: {
        endpoint: 'https://myappsync.example.com/graphql',
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        // Set the default auth mode to "apiKey" and provide the API key value
        //defaultAuthMode: 'userPool',
        defaultAuthMode: 'apiKey',
        apiKey: 'xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      }
    }
});
createApp(App).use(router).use(store).mount('#app')
```

in the page view file I use this code in the vue mounted function,
it permits me to listen for DynamoDb modifications

```
import { generateClient } from 'aws-amplify/api';
import * as subscriptions from '@/graphql/subscriptions';

export default {

...

mounted(){
    const client = generateClient();
    const updateSub = client
    .graphql({ query: subscriptions.onUpdateOrders })
    .subscribe({
      next: ({ data }) => console.log(data),
      error: (error) => console.warn(error)
    });    
  },

...

}
```

I tried configure Amplify in my main.js like this, passing a Cognito user token but it does not work

```
Amplify.configure({
    API: {
      GraphQL: {
        endpoint: 'https://appsync.example.com/graphql',
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        defaultAuthMode: 'userPool',
        headers: async () => ({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxx'
        })
        /*defaultAuthMode: 'apiKey',
        apiKey: 'xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx',*/
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This article describes multiple provider for authentication. There are some other topics from same author that can be helpful. https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-cognito-with-appsync/